# Dynamically sized children of WrapPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, layout

I have a list of texts placed in [WrapPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.wrappanel?view=net-5.0), representing nested text blocks... The texts are clickable so I wanted to emphasize it, so when user enters mouse over them, I make them bigger (basically I'm just increasing the font by one). The problem is that this changes size of the framework element which affects layout in `WrapPanel`, meaning the panel can move last item into next row.  Normally there is enough space, or even if not, it's not a problem when hovering over some text in the middle. But if user want's to click last element when it's near the edge of the panel, he basically can't. Because as soon as the element grows, it moves to next row and the cursor is not longer over it, so it shrinks again and panel moves it back to first row, where it is under cursor again, and so on...

Here you can see this scenario:

[image]
[image]

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
    public MainWindow() {
        InitializeComponent();

        var wp = new WrapPanel() {
            Background = Brushes.Blue,
            Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
            VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
            Children = {
                createChild(),
                createChild(),
                createChild(),
                createChild(),
            }
        };
        Content = new Grid() {
            Background = Brushes.Gray,
            Children = { wp }
        };
    }

    private UIElement createChild() {
        var g = new Grid() {
            Width = 100,
            Height = 20,
            Margin = new Thickness(5),
            Background = Brushes.Red,
        };
        g.MouseEnter += (s, e) => { g.Width *= 2; g.Background = Brushes.White; };
        g.MouseLeave += (s, e) => { g.Width *= .5; g.Background = Brushes.Red; };
        return g;
    }
}
```

How can I avoid it?

I was thinking of some "margin" property I could specify in `WrapPanel` so it will move the child to next row earlier when it's close to the edge whiting that margin (even if it could actually fit), but I didn't found such thing.

Comment: Quite obviously, changing the size of the text element and hence the resulting layout is not a great idea. Maybe change the Foreground, or set the FontWeight to Bold.

Comment: Or apply a ScaleTransform to the RenderTransform of an element, which would not affect layout.

Comment: You should consider to trigger on keyboard focus instead of mouse over. This should feel a bit more natural opposed to controls jumping across the screen on mouse over will provide a quite annoying experience. Also you should prevent the control from wrapping.  Just keep it in place and use available space to stretch the control. Additionally, you could also shrink other boxes to provide more space for the focused box.

Comment: @BionicCode Keyboard focus in not an option for me. How can I determine available space? I don't know ahead neither count nor widths of displayed elements so it seams tricky.

Comment: @Clemens I though about RenderTransform but last time and used it, I had some blurring images...